# How do you solve $2|x+1|^2 = 3|x+1| + 2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Do you just change the absolute value signs with parentheses?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $|x + 1| = A$. Then we have the quadratic equation $2A^2 = 3A + 2$, or $2A^2 - 3A - 2 = 0$. Factoring, we have that $(2A + 1)(A - 2) = 0$. This yields $A =-1/2$ and $A = 2$. $A = -1 / 2$ is not possible, so$ A = |x + 1| = 2$, solving, we get $x + 1 = -2$ or $2$, and $x = -3$ or $1$.

Comment: Please use MathJax for formatting. Your answers will be better received.

Comment: Thank you for formatting my solution.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** What if, instead of $\lvert x+1\rvert$, the equation had $y$?
$$
2y^2=3y+2
$$

How would you solve it then?

Once you've found values for $y$ that satisfy this equation, "remember" that $y=\lvert x+1\rvert$.

Comment: Thank you! Should've noticed that. I was too focused on the absolute value being squared.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Set $t=\lvert x+1\rvert$, solve the quadratic equation for $t$, then solve $\lvert x+1\rvert=t\;$ (this last equation implies $t$ is a non-negative solution of the quadratic equation).